# delay in dynamic image load in ios

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios

I have implemented a simple jquery carousel for mobile devices which has three containers for three images at a time. I have used jquery for the animation. Depending on the user's swipe direction, left or right, I update the contents of the relevant image container. The contents include the image's src path and the image title in a div tag. This works fine across all Android devices, but I am getting a delay in image load in iOS devices. Due to this, there is a flickering when the previous image is replaced with a new one. How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add 2 more containers off screen (one at each side) to pre-load the images and scroll them in when needed. This is a very common design.

Comment: I think that will work. Can you provide some insight into the possible reasons for this delay, that too specifically in iOS? I may be unaware of something I should know.

Comment: Are you loading your images from disk/web ?

Comment: I am loading images from web.

Comment: Do you cache them or do you reload them each time you try to display them ?

Comment: Yes, they are cached.

Comment: If they are cached on disk, you have to wait for the i/o operation to finish before the image can be displayed. And it takes time. If it's on RAM, you still have the display time. It's always a good practice to preload whatever is going to be shown. UITableViews preload 1 row off screen at each end of the tableView for example.